# Generate database table diagrams from a PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql

I am looking for a GUI program that can generate database table diagrams from a PostgreSQL database. I am aware of [SchemaSpy](http://schemaspy.sourceforge.net/), [SchemaCrawler](http://sualeh.github.io/SchemaCrawler/) and [PostgreSQL Autodoc](https://github.com/cbbrowne/autodoc) but they are CLI. Any OS, price and license is fine.

---

A similar question was asked on SO but was closed: [tools to generate database tables diagram with postgresql?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3223770/395857)

Comment: Here is the list of recommended GUI tools in the postgres wiki.
[GUI database design tools](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/GUI_Database_Design_Tools)

Comment: @SudipBhandari: Among those what is the tool that you recommend to generate a tables diagram? Please post an answer for that particular tool and don't forget to include a screenshot of the generated diagram, thanks!

Answer (score 35):

**[DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/)** free, multi-platform universal SQL client. Supports all popular databases: MySQL, PostgreSQL, MariaDB, SQLite, Oracle, DB2, SQL Server, Sybase, MS Access, Teradata, Firebird, Derby, etc.

You can do all crud operations as well as Advances operations from here. Supports N number of database types (Relational/NoSQL)

[image]

Comment: Gets the job done in the community edition. Used for Postgres. Recomended

Comment: <1 min to set up and connect to PostgreSQL database.  Here's the documentation on bringing up the ER diagram as in @Akshay-Gupta's answer. https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/wiki/ER-Diagrams

Comment: Thanks, worked well with Postgres in mac. Had to download and attach dependencies though.

Comment: amazing works great!

Answer (score 8):

Inspired by the [answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/64256) by @arman-fatahi, here is a more detailed instruction how to create DB diagrams using draw.io:

1. Dump the schema of your database - e.g. for PostgreSQL, the command might be:

```
pg_dump -s mydb > mydb_dump.sql
```

2. Create a blank diagram on [draw.io](https://draw.io). Choose from the dropdown menu: `Arrange` > `Insert` > `Advanced` > `SQL...`

[image: Insert SQL]

3. Paste the dumped database schema in the window that opens:

[image: Sample SQL code]

4. The tables' diagrams will be automatically generated, you can rearrange them and add the arrows representing the relations between them:

[image]

Comment: i love this one

Comment: i think the only missing thing is maintaining the schema during time. I had a database with > 100 tables, and it would be a hell to arrange and adjust colors for every table (and usually you need a diagram for the actual DB, not for something you had 3 months ago)

Answer (score 6):

You may use ["Microolap Database Designer for PostgreSQL"](http://microolap.com/products/database/postgresql-designer/) aka PgMDD

It's a commercial software with 30-day trial though. Personal\Educational license will cost $124.95, however you may get a free license also (details on the order page).

Here is a quick tutorial on how to Reverse Engineer (Import) PostgreSQL database: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pj3-3VkW3qM

1. Select File | Reverse Engineer | PostgreSQL database or press Ctrl-R.
   [image: PgMDD Reverse Engineer]
2. If connection for the current diagram has not been established, Database Connection Manager will be shown. Select a profile from the list of the available ones or create a new profile to connect to the database you want to revere engineer.
   [image: PgMDD Connection Manager]
3. The PostgreSQL Database Reverse Engineering tool will be shown. You can set the reverse engineering options in the Options tab.
   [image: PostgreSQL Database Reverse Engineering tool]
4. In the Selection tab of the PostgreSQL Database Reverse Engineering tool you can choose the objects you want to reverse engineer.
   [image: Selection tab of the PostgreSQL Database Reverse Engineering tool]
5. Click OK to start the database reverse engineering process.
   [image: reverse engineering process]
6. The reversed database objects will be placed in your diagram.
   [image: Chinook database diagram]

Answer (score 5):

You can use [SQL Power Architect](http://www.sqlpower.ca/page/architect):

- Most features are free, including the ER schema generation
- Microsoft Windows / Mac OS X / Linux
- Supports most commonplace DBMS suggest MySQL and PostgreSQL

You just need to  drag-and-drop to generate the visual schema:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Worked well for a quick and dirty reverse-engineered diagram.  Threw a lot of exceptions in the process though. :)

Comment: You can also export it as a pdf or generate an HTML document with description of each of the table along with the hyperlink to the linked tables.. neat

Comment: SQL Power Architect needs Java to run (which I can't use)

Answer (score 4):

[Datagrip](https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/) by Jetbrains. Apart from PostgreSQL it works with various RDBMS (MYSQL, SQL Server, MongoDB,...).

They have a 30 day trial and there are [various pricing options](https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/buy/#personal?billing=yearly).

Here's how to do it: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/creating-diagrams.html

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is the best way that I found:

1. Export your database schema as SQL. Most databases have a tool for that.
2. Go to Draw.io and open an empty file.
3. Click the plus on the top ( [help](https://about.draw.io/entity-relationship-diagrams-with-draw-io/) )
4. Select from SQL and paste your sql script.
5. Rearrange your tables.

This is easiest way to do it without installing any software.

Comment: This sounds good. Can you post a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

Try [DbSchema](http://www.dbschema.com), it's commercial software with free trial. It works with a couple of RDBMS and NoSQL databases. It generates interactive diagrams with clear layout and can export to SVG/png/jpg.

Comment: Please add a screenshot, thanks! The screenshot must show the step when you generate a diagram from an existing database.

Comment: DbSchema needs Java to run (which I can't use)

Answer (score 0):

You may use PgModeler. It is open source software and works fine on Linux.
http://www.pgmodeler.com.br/

1. run pgmodeler, click on import, select connection and database then click on import. (don't forget to edit connections to set your db-user and password)

[image: run pgmodeler, click on import, select connection and database then click on import.]

2. Once done you may work on your model.

[image: Once done you may work on your Model.]

after working on your model you can export it to an .sql file or export the changes to your connected database

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please add screenshot and price/license, or this answer will be deleted, thanks! Please read http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/356/what-is-required-for-an-answer-to-be-high-quality Cheers!

Comment: The screenshot must show the step when you generate a diagram from an existing database.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using [Valentina Studio](https://www.valentina-db.com/en/valentina-studio-overview)

Here is a diagram I created. I noticed if the foreign keys had the same name (in different tables) it would only show one of the links. When I named the foreign key constraints with different names it fixed the diagram.

[image: jpg of Valintina diagram]

Comment: good luck if you don't have permission to rename foreign key names...